# Set in domain not working after upgrading grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

Recently I upgraded grails from 1.3.4 to 2.2.2 and I'm getting following error while trying to iterate over a Set defined as hasMany in a domain.

```
class A {
 String name
 static hasMany = [bList: B]
}

class B {
 static belongsTo = [a:A]
}

class TestController {
 def test = {
  A a = A.get(1L)
  def bList = a.bList
  bList.each{}
 }
}
```

Above line ***bList.each {}*** is throwing following exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
>
> at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:46)
>
> at
>   com.test.TestController$_closure2.doCall(TestController.groovy:5)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Comment: You do have `hibernate` plugin mentioned in `BuildConfig`? right?

Comment: As its an upgrade hibernate plugin is specified in application.properties "plugins.hibernate=2.2.2" everything else works all crud operations are working accept this.

Comment: The plugins shouldn't be specified there. They should be in BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: Suggestion: Create a sample app in 2.2.2 and compare it with your upgraded app. Or copy over the content and settings to the newly created app in 2.2.2. By that way you will not miss anything crucial in the newer version of grails. Also there are prerequisites for a smooth upgrade which I guess you would have already looked around.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I know but this is how it is when you upgrade btw now I have moved them to BuildConfig nothing changed.

Comment: @dmahapatro current app is a big app with some custom scripts and other stuff just copy pasting into new project won't make it work its a big task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue

Class B had a **afterLoad()** event hook attached to it which for some weird reason was throwing ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments*** exception I have now changed it to **onLoad()** Happy Days Now.

Thanks
Hussain